# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have very strange situation.
The following code is working on my localhost, but on my server it is not working.

I got the error "Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'beteu.bets' doesn't exist". The Model is looking not in the right database, that's why it cannot find the table. But he is not supposed to look in that database.

In the function, where I am calling the method i have made following test to check what is the active database:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo();
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
    echo "Yes! Successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
}
die();
```

So here as a result I got the correct database "soccerbets", but than I try to output all results in the "bets" table like that:

```
DB::connection()->getPdo();
if(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()){
    echo "Yes! Successfully connected to the DB: " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
    print_r(Bet::get());
}
die();
```

And here I got again the strange error:
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'beteu.bets' doesn't exist

Here is the code of the Bet model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bet extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'ip', 'site', 
    ];

}
```

I have tried also to define explicit the database in that Model, but nothing happens.

Please help me find that stupid error :)

Answer (score -1):

The variable you are looking for in your model is

```
protected $connection = "connection of your second db name";
```

You also have to define a new connection (database) in your /config/database.php

If you don't want to expose your credentials in versioning, you also have to add at least one new .env variable to set the connection.

So similar to your default "mysql" connection, you can add a new connection, you can set the default connection in your .env

Comment: thank you for your comment, but please check the sentence before the last one :)

Comment: @VinceCarter according to your snippet, you did not do that.